# Javascript/Php - Redirect when action form page typed directly in URL

Tags: javascript, php

I am wanting to know if it is possible to redirect a page (to a home page) if the Url is typed directly in the address box, without it affecting my form action page.

When the user logs in, it redirects to separate page (cust_login). However, if the user is redirected to the cust_login page and then presses the refresh button (or goes to the cust_login page directly), my css is messed up and it all looks a shambles.

If anyone can help me on this, I would be grateful.

Example

```
<form action="localhost/cust_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
<input type="text" name="username" class="box" value="Email Address"/>
<input type="text" name="password" class="box" value="Password"/>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

This login form would be included on every page.

Comment: A bit of code would help someone debug.

Comment: if is form redirect....check that there is a post, if not redirect from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out using PHP (Thanks to @HarshaBhat who made me realise that this could be PHP too).

Basically my form action would be included in each page, therefore trying to use php header to send user to home page would inevitably cause a redirect loop.

Therefore on each page except the cust_login.php I have included a $login_check set to true.

Then on the cust_login.php I have put the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{ // 
}elseif(isset($login_check)){ 
// 
}else{ 
header("Location: localhost/home.php"); 
exit; 
} –
```